# BULK INSERT data from .csv Errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, sql-server-2019

Went trough all other questions regarding this topic.

I have the following dataset:

```
10330   30-Jun-2009 Pogo stick  1   28,00
10101   30-Jun-2009 Raft        1   58,00
10298   01-Jul-2009 Skateboard  1   33,00
```

I am creating a table for it like so:

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE
        TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'Customer_Purchases'
)   BEGIN
        SELECT
            -1;
        RETURN;
    END 
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE [TelenorAssignment].[dbo].[Customer_Purchases] (
            customerid INT NOT NULL,
            order_date DATE NULL,
            item VARCHAR NULL,
            quantity VARCHAR NULL,
            price VARCHAR NULL,
            CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerPurchases_CustomerID FOREIGN KEY (customerid)
                REFERENCES [TelenorAssignment].[dbo].[Customers](customerid)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
        )
    END
GO
```

Ant trying to BULK IMPORT like so:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BULK INSERT [TelenorAssignment].[dbo].[Customer_Purchases]
    FROM
        'C:\Users\tsenk\OneDrive\customer_purchases_data.csv' WITH (
            FIRSTROW = 1,
            FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
            ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
            ERRORFILE = 'C:\Users\tsenk\OneDrive\CustomerPurchasesDataErrorRows.csv',
            TABLOCK
        )
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  SELECT
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
    ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
    ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
    ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
    ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
    ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
GO
```

I receive two errors:

1. Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 3 (item);
2. Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Tried 'SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF' with no change in the result.

What may be the cause of this?

Comment: "Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 3 (item)" Seems pretty obvious to me that you have a field too long. You haven't declared `VARCHAR` lengths in you DDL, it will default to 30.

Comment: @Charlieface, what do you think is causing the second error?

Comment: You create your table with a three part name but your existence check is relative to the current database of the connection. That's just plain sloppy coding. And you should throw an error to indicate an ERROR, not return an anonymous resultset with a single row/column containing -1. And don't try to fiddle with connection settings like ansi_warnings without a very good reason and a very good understanding of the potential consequences.

Comment: I think that's just the same error bubbled up

Comment: @SMor, thanks for the constructive criticism. That is the way to create a table that I have in the course bought on Udemy. What other way would you suggest to be considered 'non-sloppy'?

Comment: @Charlieface corrected the data type of field 3  to 'VARCHAR (200)' and it imported the data to the table. +1